# How to send post to 2 different actions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, post

I have some HTML and Javascript code that sends a form using method=post to an action="www.randomaction.com/randomaction.php".

Now I want to see exactly how it sends it to the action by also sending it to my mail (the same post), however I don't want to have the site open the users mail client to do this, I want it to send from my gmail account to my other gmail account.

my code looks like this:

```
<form action="http://www.randomaction.com/shared/AddClient/index.php" class="form hod-hasharon" data-name="Email Form Hod Hasharon" data-redirect="http://www.kbanim.com/landing-pages/thank-you" id="wf-form-Email-Form-Hod-Hasharon-2" method="post" name="wf-form-Email-Form-Hod-Hasharon" redirect="http://www.kbanim.com/landing-pages/thank-you">
    <div class="w-embed w-script">
      <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        <!--
            var MediaTitle= document.URL;
          if(MediaTitle.includes("facebook"))
              {
                  MediaTitle= "facebook";
              }
          if(MediaTitle.includes("googles"))
              {
                  MediaTitle= "google search";
              }
          if(MediaTitle.includes("googlem"))
              {
                  MediaTitle= "google media";
              }
          if(MediaTitle.includes("googler"))
              {
                  MediaTitle= "google remraketing";
              }
        document.write('<input type=hidden data-name="MetaTitle" id="MetaTitle" name="MetaTitle" required="required" ');
        document.write('   value="' + document.URL + '">');
        document.write('<input type=hidden data-name="Password" id="Password" name="Password" required="required" value="jkq0105">');
        document.write('<input type=hidden data-name="ProjectID" id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" required="required" value="6661">');
      //-->
      </script>
    </div>
    <input class="_3 hod-hasharon text-field w-input" data-name="Fname" id="Fname" maxlength="256" name="Fname" placeholder="שם מלא:" required="required" type="text">
    <input class="_2 hod-hasharon text-field w-input" data-name="Phone" id="Phone" maxlength="256" name="Phone" placeholder="טלפון:" required="required" type="text">
    <input class="hod-hasharon text-field w-input" data-name="Email" id="Email" maxlength="256" name="Email" placeholder="מייל:" required="required" type="email">
    <input class="submit-button w-button" data-wait="שולח..." type="submit" value="  שליחה &gt;&gt;">
  </form>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The method POST doesn't send anything visible to the page.

Your POST information will be available in a PHP array in your PHP file :

```
$_POST
```

If you want to access a single value from your form :

```
$_POST['yourInputID']
```

Comment: the action link to the randomaction.php file is not mine, it is another company's script.
Can I send both to that file and a mail with all the inputs I'm sending to it?

Comment: You could replace randomaction.php by another php file you created. In this one you send your mail, then send a POST to the previous randomaction.php via [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/).